# how to connect database to PHP using class

Tags: php, mysql

I created db_manager.php file.. i.e.

```
class db_manager
{
    function DBLogin() 
        {

        $this->connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "careerknots");

        if(!$this->connection)
        {               
            return false;
        }
        return true;
      }
    }
```

This is my `upload_resume_action.php` file.

```
require_once("db_manager.php");
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) 
{
    $db_manager = new db_manager();
    $con = $db_manager->DBLogin();
    if(!$con)
    {
        echo "Database login failed!";
    }
    $cname = $_POST["uname"];
    $cmob = $_POST["mob"];
    $cemail = $_POST["email"];
    $cfile = $_POST["myfile"];
    $sql = "insert into res_detail(name,mobile,email,resume_loc) values ('$cname','$cmob','$cemail','$cfile')";
    $done = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if($done)
    {
        echo "records added successfully";
    }
}
```

I’m getting error in `mysqli_query` in first parameter. It is saying that it is expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php

Comment: `$con` is always a Boolean. You are returning either true or false in `DBLogin()`. Try returning the reference there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It worked after I replaced `$con` with `$db_manager->connection` in `mysqli_query` in `upload_resume_action.php`

Answer (score 1):

1. class `db_manager` not isset `connect` property
2. method `DBlogin` return bool. Should return `$this->connection`